# "overloading" variables when defining functions

Tags: python

In Python it is possible to "reuse" variable names in function definitions.  For example, one can define the function f(x,y) = x + y^2 as follows:

```
def f(x,y):
    def square(x):
        return x**2
    return square(y)+x
```

This works because Python knows that the x in the definition of square(x) refers to the argument of square(), not the x in f(x,y)

But would one ever run into problems when doing more complicated versions of this?  Is this considered bad programming practice?  For example, would the following be better?

```
def f(x,y):
    def square(z):
        return z**2
    return square(y)+x
```

Comment: Flat is better than nested. ([zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)) Of course there are cases where defining function inside function is OK, but the example case is not one of them.

Comment: I fail to see the difference? You'd be defining the same function in the same module, or different modules? Anyway your Linter might complain that you have duplicate code in your project.

Comment: He is asking whether It's a good practice to use the same variable name in this case `x`

Comment: @buran I know, I just came up with a contrived example for the sake of this question

Comment: I've edited the example slightly, to better illustrate the question I am trying to ask.

Comment: Usually your linter will complain that you are "shadowing a variable form an outer scope" but that's about it.

Comment: Yes, the second version is better IMO. If things get more complex, you don't want two `x` around. Also, the first one will still work if you remove the argument from the inner function signature, but the result will be different. I'd prefer the second one as it would raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed it is possible, in fact this practice has a name - *wrapping*. But this method hogs more memory as you define a method each time one is called so this is not used in matters as simple as this. But with modules like tensorflow where you have to define custom input functions for each new instance of TF's class this is very useful as you can just return a function.